# Where is GetTickCount after Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, indy

I am trying to migrate from Delphi 6 to Delphi 2010, but I cannot find the `GetTickCount` function in Delphi 2010. I have `IdGlobal`, `SysUtils`, and `DateUtils` in my uses clause.

```
var
  RefreshTick : Cardinal;
begin
  RefreshTick := GetTickCount;
end;
```

It gives me an error:

> Undeclared identifier : GetTickCount

What's an alternative to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've since discovered, the `GetTickCount` function you were using was provided by the IdGlobal unit. It had the same name as a Windows API function. **The function you were using is now named `Ticks`.** Either add Windows to your uses clause to get the API function, or change your code to use the new name instead.

It looks like the name change came sometime in 2004. You should try to be more diligent about keeping your Indy library up to date. Don't just use the version that comes with Delphi — it was probably outdated before you even got it. Always download the latest version from Indy's source control.

Comment: `IdGlobal.GetTickCount()` existed in Indy 9 and earlier, was renamed to `IdGlobal.Ticks()` in Indy 10.

Answer (score 11):

The [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is part of the Windows unit.

Comment: In [Delphi 6,IdGlobal](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidF25CF09400A60A820DBF932BE51B6D0FB02771B6.aspx) had `GetTickCount` funtion in it,but in[Delphi 2010, IdGlobal](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid055397A1232303A5193C786F35AAB7509F9D7027.aspx)
funtion is is absent

Comment: D6 shipped with Indy 8.  `IdGlobal.GetTickCount()` was renamed in Indy 10 to stop conflicting with `Windows.GetTickCount()`.

Answer (score 0):

`GetTickCount` doesn't depend on Delphi's version because it's a WinAPI function and it must be there in Delphi 2010 too, also in Delphi XE and XE2.

EDIT: Add Windows unit to your uses section.

Comment: I have `IDGlobal, SysUtils, DateUtils` in my uses section

Comment: The Win32 API `GetTickCount()` function is in the `Windows` unit, not the `SysUtils` unit.

Answer (score 0):

With Lazarus 1.0.12 the next commands worked ok in windows:

Uses ...Windows...

here is the code:

```
Var
  initialtime, elapsedtime: DWord;
  .
begin
  .
 initialtime := Windows.GetTickCount;
  .
 elapsedtime := Windows.GetTickCount - initialtime;

 WriteLn( 'Time elapsed: ' + IntToStr(elapsedtime) + ' miliseconds');
```

Comment: please always give some details about your answer,for better understanding